# How to get sample rate from Keysight 34461A DMM using SCPI

Tags: python, automation, measurement, pyvisa

How can I get the actual sample rate of a Keysight 34461A DMM using SCPI commands?

Comment: is this done by the `SAMPle:TIMer?` query

Comment: ...or is this just one of the parameters from which the SR is calculated?

Comment: SAMPLe:TIMer does not work for the 34461A. You need to calculate the Sample Rate with the (Sampling Time/counts of measurements).

Comment: Yeah, I was worried, that's the case.